# Multiplication returns incorrect value for large numbers x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to write a simple program in C (using extern assembly function) which converts kg to pounds. Here is the function in C and how its being called:

```
extern int convert(int value, int factor);

printf("Value in Pounds: %lf\n", convert(value, 2205)/1000.0); // doing division in C since I could not figure out how to work with floating point in assembler
```

However, when the "value" parameter is too large (I want it to work on a 9 digit integer), the value calculated is incorrect. How can I fix the problem?
Here is the assembly code:

```
.globl _convert

_convert:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
movl 8(%ebp), %eax # get value
movl 12(%ebp), %ecx # get factor
mull %ecx
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

I also tried writing the loop which iterates "factor" amount of times and adds "value" to itself, but I get same results.

Comment: " too large" is not specific enough. Please provide actual intput, actual and expected output. Also note that the maximum `int` is typically `2^31-1=2147483647`.

Comment: @Jester, somewhere around a million as an input the output starts to go into negative values

Comment: Also I mentioned that I want it to work on a 9 digit integer

Comment: Seriously, you put all that effort into typing those comments instead of giving a specific input? Anyway, as I said, the maximum for a 32 bit `int` is `2147483647`. Since you are multiplying by `2205` that means inputs around 1 million will overflow. Use a 64 bit data type instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9 digits is too large, since 999999999 · 2.20642 > 2^31, so it will be a negative number. Use unsigned 32 bit integer instead, or limit the input to a maximum of 974083355.

You could also try using 3 parameters so conversion factor is an integer fraction for better accuracy:

```
extern unsigned int convert(int value, int numerator, int denominator);

    convert(num, 220462, 100000);


        .globl  _convert
_convert:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax  # get value
        movl    12(%ebp), %ecx # get numerator
        mull    %ecx           # edx:eax = product
        movl    16(%ebp), %ecx # get denominator
        divl    %ecx           # eax = quotient
        add     %edx,%edx      # round
        cmp     %ecx,%edx
        cmc
        adc     0,%eax
        movl    %ebp, %esp
        popl    %ebp
        ret
```